# Number Theory - Sum of Squares and Quadratic Residue

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Show that if $p$ is a prime number satisfying $p\equiv 1\mod 4$, $a$ is an odd positive number, and there exists $b$ such that $a^2+b^2=p$, then $a$ is a quadratic residue $\mod p$.

I know that Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares tells us that $a^2+b^2=p$ iff $p\equiv 1\mod 4$. Also I believe a form of Wilson's Theorem could be used here, although I'm not sure how.

Comment: What do you know about residues for primes equivalent to $1$ mod $4$?

Comment: That $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is even and therefore $a^{even power} \equiv 1 \mod p$?

Comment: More specifically what do you know about $-1$?

Comment: Oh $-1$ is a quadratic residue $\mod p$ if $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$. So Wilson's theorem gives $p \mid (a^2 + 1)$. How does that tie in to $p = a^2 + b^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$, where $p_i$ are odd, since $a$ is odd.

$b^2\equiv p\pmod{p_i}$, so $\left(\frac{p}{p_i}\right)=1$.

$\left(\frac{p}{p_i}\right)=\left(\frac{p_i}{p}\right)=1$ by Quadratic Reciprocity, since $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p_1}{p}\right)^{a_1}\left(\frac{p_2}{p}\right)^{a_2}\cdots \left(\frac{p_k}{p}\right)^{a_k}=1\cdot 1\cdots 1=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $a$ is an odd **prime**, then the equation $a^2+b^2 = p$ says that $p$ is a quadratic residue mod $a$.  Since $p = 4k+1$, quadratic reciprocity then guarantees that $a$ is a prime mod $p$.  I leave it to you to generalize this argument to $a$ odd and composite.

Comment: How do you say that if $a$ is an odd prime, then the equation $a^2 + b^2 = p$ means that $p$ is a quadratic residue mod $a$? I mean, I get that $b^2 \equiv p \mod a$ but how does this imply that $p$ is a residue?

Comment: @Rohit We have $p = b^2 \bmod a$ since $a$ divides $a^2 = p-b^2$.

Comment: Thank you, this is correct.